# AgoraRTC and webRTC

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Can we combine AgoraRTC and WebRTC in flutter, if possible please, let me know

I'm using agoraRTC package but it not supported in Web side, this is the issue I faced, Still i'm trying to do the process but I can not solve this issue, I anyone know just teach me